# Building ngx-bootstrap locally

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

Simple, I cloned the repository of ngx-bootstrap and tried to build it locally.

To execute `npm install` to took me about 4 hours (because of the infinite problems which I get)
after a huge effort, I managed to install the packages.

then comes the next step `npm run build` here I faced with the following problem

> Building collapse module 
> Error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /q /s /c "npm run dist-to-modules"
> 'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I understand that the `cp` is Linux based command and it will not work in windows, I tried to change to play with the command in the script section in the `package.json` but without luck, it did not work.

my question is, if somebody wants to build ngx-bootstrap on Windows, why there is no guide for them to do that, why it is only for Linux?

how should I change the following command

```
"dist-to-modules": "cp -R ./dist/. ./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap"
```

to make it work on windows? 
I am really frustrated, building a library should not be such a hard task

Answer (score 0):

You have to use copy instead of cp.  Just update the script.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, we had an issue with the Windows build, and, Barry helped with that :)
Gonna be fixed in 6.1.0 version, which will be released in a few weeks, I think, or, earlier